# how can i run my html file with live server in chrome browser

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, liveserver

so I want to open html file with live server extension but in chrome browser , I don't know why but it's always open in edge browser

Comment: Probably because your default browser is edge. You can change that in the settings of your device. Also you can just copy the link of the localhost and paste it in the chrome search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the fact that Edge may be set as your default browser. Go to your Settings app, search "Default Browser" and modify your OS' default browser that way.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this command `live-server --port=8080 --browser=chrome`